# java while loop throwing exception

Tags: java

the first line takes the size of the array to follow.The array's digits are checked to see if they can form a ambiguous permutation.

```
public class Codechef2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int intnum=10;
        intnum=input.nextInt();

        input.nextLine();
        String a[]=new String[100000];
        int count=0;
        int i=0;

        While(intnum>0)
        {
            a[i]=input.nextLine();
            String arr[]=a[i].split(" ");
            int aj[]=new int[arr.length];
            int k=0;
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
            {

                aj[Integer.parseInt(arr[k])]=j+1;
                k++;

            }

            for(int l=0;l<arr.length;l++)
            {
                if(aj[l]==Integer.parseInt(arr[l]))
                count++;
                }

            if(count==arr.length)
                System.out.println("ambiguous permutation");
            else
                System.out.println("Not ambiguous permutation");

            intnum=input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "java while loop throwing exception" Isn't enough information to debug this problem.

Comment: At least give the exact message about the exception. You should have a stacktrace that tells you which line in your program throws the exception — tell us which. With that information it’s not unlikely someone around here can spot the cause immediately. So it’s for your own sake. You may want to read more about how to ask a good question in the help center.

Comment: `String aj[]=new aj[arr.length];` ?  Did you mean `String[] aj=new String[arr.length];` ?

Comment: The new code posted does not compile.  `While(intnum>0);` is wrong. If so how do run it ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
Again: pleas post a compilable code:

```
//wrong
//While(intnum>0)
while(intnum>0)
```

Also:

```
//you need to print a msg so the user knows that he / she
//needs to input and tell the user what to input
System.out.println("Please enter ....");
input.nextLine();
```

---

The code has many errors.

For example :

```
String aj[]=new aj[arr.length]; //will not compile
While(intnum>0)    //will not compile
a[i]=input.nextLine(); //will not compile. i is defined later.
aj[arr[k]]=i+1; //wrong : aj[] is a String. i+1 is an int.
```

Fix them and post a compilable code.

Comment: It's not compiling that is what the problem is. If it was compiling why would i  post it in the first place sir ?

Comment: To get help with wrong output. Please fix what's needed and ask what is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Code below the while loop is not executed until the conditions of the while loop are met.